# Opera Next issue

Tags: google-translate

Google translate's "Listen" function is not working, i.e. no sound is played if I click the listen button, in my Opera 18.0.1284.68 on Windows 8 64 bit. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, though. I tried disabling the add-ons too.

Any suggestion, please.

Comment: AFAIK the "listen" function / sound is provided by Flash (add-on), so disabling the add-ons is probably not going to help.

Comment: Has it ever worked? Did you try the Opera support pages? Are your add-ons up to date?

Comment: @w3d yes buddy, all up to date .. and i googled for the issue, if it were in support page it might have come up and if i am correct, flash is a plugin, i disabled add-ons(extension) only, and i turned them off thinking there might be clashes...

Comment: @slybolty, i didn't try g-translate on opera before that, i mean, i ran into the problem in the first go

Comment: FWIW it works OK for me in Opera 12.16 (it was all downhill from there).

Comment: @w3d maybe this problem occurred in opera NEXT, as they changed their engine.. opera 12.16 uses the old engine, i guess...